# Regular Expression in Java to find the colon in the string

Tags: java, regex

I want to distinguish the Strings between the string contains integer at the end and the String contains integer at the end but does not have a colon in it. I try to find the solution a bit but not succeed. I am new to a regular expression. What I have tried so far is.

```
("^.+?\\d$")) works good if the string is libbz2-1.0
```

But in this case for this input "lighttpd:i386" it treats the same way as it contains the integer at the end. I am not able to tell that treat it in a different way as it contains the colon in it.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give input and output expected example ?

Comment: Input = libattr1
 ,libbz2-1.0
, libc6
 ,libgamin0
 ,libfam0
 ,libldap-2.4-2
 ,libpcre3
 .libssl1.0.0 = Library 
Input = init-system-helpers
 ,perl
 ,lsb-base
 ,systemd
 ,mime-support
 ,libterm-readline-perl-perl
 ,spawn-fcgi
 ,openssl
 ,rrdtool
 ,apache2-utils
, ufw
 ,lighttpd:i386= Package

Comment: Try sth like `[a-z][-a-z]+\d(?= )$` - it works well on the input you provided: https://regex101.com/r/wBrTlE/2 (replaced end-of-string matcher with lookahead for space in the regex101 to match multiple times in the string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert with regular expressions (try to avoid them if possible), but:

This would match any string **not** containing colon and digit:

```
^(?!.*:).+?\d$
```

[link to regex](https://regex101.com/r/yTZEYr/2)

This would match any String containing colon and digit:

```
^(?:.*:).+?\d$
```

[link to regex](https://regex101.com/r/yTZEYr/1)

Comment: @Vidhi links provided have a far better explanation then I would give (note right site tab with title Explanation).

Comment: @Vidhi to make it short, it's very similar regex to yours, I just added Negative Lookahead and Non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Try `^.+?[^\\:]\d`. This will negate colon from your output. So all strings like **abcd:09** will be ignored.

Comment: No, this will return a match, everything until colon. I think OP needs such strings to be ignored. Your regex would return `abcd`

Comment: @user9413725 the answer is still the same no effect